# Give different format to output of SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, cs50

I have a code like this to ouput data from database where first, is the firstname of an user, and birth the birthday year of the user

```
name = db.execute(f'SELECT first, birth FROM mydatabase WHERE house = "{house_roster}"') 
print(name[0])
```

and my output of my first row (print[0]) is something like this:

```
{'first': 'Cedric', 'birth': 1977}
```

How can I make it just something like this?

```
Cedric, 1977
```

Comment: `print( "{}, {}".format( name[0]["first"], name[0]["birth"] ))` if you don't need comma then even `print( name[0]["first"], name[0]["birth"] )`

Comment: preferred: `db.execute('SELECT first, birth FROM mydatabase WHERE house = ?', (house_roster, ))`. as more secure.

Comment: That was very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
print(', '.join(name[0].values()))
```

It is an universal solution, for any number and any names of fields.